# Odd item movement - very blocky?

Tags: transforms

Some yesterday I accidentally clicked/used a keyboard shortut that screwed up my item movement. Previously, when I used the arrows to move an object, the object would follow along in real time, now, the object seems to move on a tiled grid. It jumps around following my cursor instead of moving fluently.

I'm relatively new to blender, and I can't find an answer to my question anywhere :)

Thanks!